# How to get the split part after using split() method

Tags: string, arraylist, split

I'm trying to convert the text in a file into String and add each word into an ArrayList with the code below. The words should be lower case and must not include special characters, numbers should be removed (ex: "h3el1l^&o" should be "hello", "34" or "1" should be ""). For example: the text in the file is "Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austen".

```
ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {         
            String line = sc.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
                if (!word.equals("")) {
                    content.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();
```

I want to ask if it is possible to access a split part of 'words'. I tried to print the element using `System.out.print(words[5]);` but it threw an IndexOutOfBoundException (if I use words[0] it will print the whole text, not a single word: prideandprejudicebyjaneausten)

Answer (score 0):

The `hasNext()` method checks if there's another token in input which using whitespace as delimiter by fault , while the `hasNextLine()` method checks line. So by using `next()` method you've already got a word instead of a whole line.

```
ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String word = sc.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
    if (!word.equals("")) {
        content.add(word);
    }    
}
sc.close();
```

Try this and I think `content.get(0)` is what you want.